# Adding objects to ArrayList<object>

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm trying to add a list of username and password combinations from a text file (each line contains a username password pair separated by a whitespace) into an ArrayList called userList. The User constructor takes two strings a sets them as username and password. This should be simple, but for some reason when I traverse the array after the following code, all of the users have the same username and password (the last line in the text file).

See code below:

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("user_pass.txt"))

String line, username, password; 

while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {

    String separated[] = line.split(" ");

    username = separated[0];
    password = separated[1];

    userList.add(new User(username,password));
}
```

Here's how I'm traversing the arrayList:

```
        for(User u : userList){
            System.out.println(u.getUsername()+" --> "+u.getPassword());
        }
```

And here's the user class:

public class User{

```
private static String username;
private static String password;


public User(String u, String p) {

    username = u;
    password = p;
}

public String getUsername(){
    return username;
}

public String getPassword(){
    return password;
}
```

Comment: Can you post the code for your User class? What are the values of username and password each iteration of the loop?

Comment: Are the `username` and `password` fields static by any chance?

Comment: Storing username and password combinations in plain text (e.g. in your user_pass.txt file) is NEVER a good idea. You should correct that problem first.

Comment: When I print the values of username and password at each iteration they are fine (i.e. the file reading and string splitting is working properly).

Comment: keep the username and password reference inside the loop

Comment: @ErstwhileIII - Who said they are plain text?  The password in the file could just as well be a SHA hash, or some such.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `username` and `password` fields are `static` which means that they will retain a single value per field (namely the last assigned value) associated with the class. Removing the `static` keyword will make them instance variables and create a value per instance of the class

```
private String username;
private String password;
```

Answer (score 0):

The `username` and `password` fields in the `User` class are static, meaning they are global class variables (called using `User.username` and `User.password`). You should remove the `static` keyword so that individual `User` object instances can have a username and a password.

Answer (score 0):

Delete the "static" in class User before the variables username and password, and you'll probably be ok.

Or, this should work:

```
class User {
    String username, password;

    public User(String u, String p) {
        username = u;
        password = p;
    }
}


//Code in the other class
Scanner s = new Scanner(new File("user_pass.txt"));
while (scanner.hasNext()) userList.add(new User(s.next(), s.next()));
s.close();
```

}